# Symfony request query empty but there's data on $_GET variable

Tags: php, symfony

I've done a simple GET request: 
http://my-domain.example/settings/test-smtp?prefix=shop

And this is the controller that handles this request:

```
public function testSMTPConnectionAction(Request $request)
{
  var_dump($_GET);
  var_dump($request->server->get('QUERY_STRING'));
  var_dump($request->query);
  var_dump($request->query->all());
}
```

Results:

```
array(1) {
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(4) "shop"
}
string(11) "prefix=shop"
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#460 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
array(0) {
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? It wasn't supposed to be the same $_GET and $request->query?
I'm using symfony 2.6.11.

Comment: What do you see if you dump $request->query->get('prefix')?

Comment: Just tried with your code and it works: `array(1) {
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(4) "shop"
}
string(11) "prefix=shop"
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["prefix"]=>
    string(4) "shop"
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(4) "shop"
}`

Comment: Hello I have exactly the same issue.

I can't figure out whats happening, and My code was working. NowI have empty data in $request->query->get(...) but if I print_r $_GET I have data.... did you solved your issue? Please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach:

```
$request->attributes->get('prefix');
```

Regards